# Does Kitematic 0.7.6 for Windows support Volumes?

Tags: windows, docker

I am able to run the hello-world-nginx Docker container running Kitematic on Windows 7. The following tutorial shows that the website_files is accessible from the Mac Finder:
https://kitematic.com/docs/nginx-web-server/

On Windows, I do not see the Edit Files section in Kitematic and the Volumes tab is empty.

I am new to Docker, Kitematic and VirtualBox.

Are volumes supported yet in Kitematic 0.7.6 for Windows? I was not prompted to mount a volume and I don't see any way to do it in Kitematic.

Answer (score 1):

I just installed today on windows 10 and yes it supports volumes, but actually thats based on the image configuration. I see you have posted this long time ago, give it another go ur update what do u have and you should find it there.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Still doens't always work in latest version... 1.10.3 ## Heading ##]

Guess only in the OSX version you can always alter them... for the latest mongo it works on Win too, but it also has the mounts directly in the dockerfile:
https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/191cc63288fb44c2fd147eac27ade07ae4b6b0b5/3.2/Dockerfile#L58

Guess it can be easily added too any dockerfile in a similar way then.